# Отказано в доступе из под рута

Tags: linux, sudo

Установил FTP-сервер pure-ftpd.
Хочу настроить.
Конфига у сервера нет.
Настройки он воспринимает так: в каталоге /etc/pure-ftpd/conf
находятся файлы, каждый из которых отвечает за один параметр.
Чтоб настроить что-то нужно создать файл с определённым именем и в нём написать "yes" или "no".

Пытаюсь сделать это:

`sudo echo no > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/someparam`

На что мне отвечают:

`An error occurred while redirecting file '/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/someparam' 
open: Permission denied`

Как у root'а может отсутствовать доступ?

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте, пожалуйста, его принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Answer (score 4):

> sudo echo no > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/someparam

от имени привилегированного пользователя выполняется процесс, запущенный командой `echo no`.

а манипуляции с перенаправленным потоком *stdout* осуществляет уже текущий процесс оболочки, который, судя по всему, не имеет прав на запись в указанный файл.

---

можно пойти двумя путями:

1. именно запись в файл осуществлять от имени привилегированного пользователя, например, так:

   ```
   $ echo no | sudo tee /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/someparam
   ```
2. выполнять от имени этого пользователя оба действия, совместив их в одну команду, передаваемую *shell*-у, например, так:

   ```
   $ sudo sh -c 'echo no > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/someparam'
   ```