# Хочу изменить файл hosts.txt, но он только для чтения

Tags: linux

Пытаюсь изменить файл hosts.txt в dir etc, но он только для чтения. Пытался через консоль, а также пересоздавать файл и заменит его, ничего не получилось

Comment: У вас диск на только чтение настроен? Или именно этот файл? Если только файл тогда через `chmod` выдавайте права, а если диск тогда тут я не силён. P.S. файл не `hosts.txt`, а просто `hosts`.

Comment: во втором случае(RO раздел) - [mount](https://losst.ru/montirovanie-diska-v-linux)

Comment: По-моему стоит начать с глупого, но важного вопроса: вы — root?

Comment: @andreymal, нет, оказывается, я не был root) 
Использую kali 2 день, думал, что sudo для этого достаточно
Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @Blinovich ну вообще sudo вполне достаточно чтобы стать root'ом, так что видимо вы что-то с sudo делали не так

Comment: вероятно, [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443246/178576)